# Difference between Left() and Left$() function in Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to debug a broken query. The query uses
Left$([blahblah],4) instead of Left([blahblah],4).

What is the difference between the Left() and Left$() functions in
Microsoft Access?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The trailing $ is a type declaration character for the String data type in
VBA.

The result returned from Left$() is a string, whereas Left() returns a
Variant.

You must use Left(), not Left$() if there is any chance of Null values,
since the Variant can be Null but the String cannot. To demonstrate that:

1. Press Ctrl+G to open the Immedate window.
2. Enter:
   ? Left(Null,1)
   The answer is Null.
3. Now enter:
   ? Left$(Null,1)
   This generates Error 94. Since the result should be Null, and the String
   cannot be Null, you receive the error, "Invalid use of Null".

If you are dealing with string values, in VBA code, Left$() will be slightly
more efficient, as it avoids the overhead/inefficieny associated with the
Variant. However, if there is *any* chance that Nulls may be involved, use
Left(), or else explicitly handle the Null with something such as Nz().

> left$() will return a string or generate an error if passed NULL
>
> left() will return a string or NULL if passed NULL

More information on Nulls:
http://allenbrowne.com/casu-11.html

Answer (score 3):

The only difference is that *Left* accepts Null while *Left$* does not.

If passed a string, *both* return a String. VarType: *vbString*

If passed Null, *Left* returns a Null value. VarType: *vbNull*

They both runs at the same speed, about 12 mio. iterations pr. second, thus of no importance. Actually, if many samples are recorded, Left in average is a fraction *faster* than Left$.

So, to put it short: Use Left$ if you wish to raise an error on a parameter value of Null, otherwise save your typing.

Comment: `Left$` forces you to treat a string as a string, which forces you to deal with `NULL` values early on, before you pass them to something that wants a `String` and blows up with a *type mismatch* or *invalid use of null*. That "save your typing" advice also extends to "rely on implicit type conversions everywhere and use `Variant` instead of `String` when you're passing values to functions and procedures. Can't agree with that.