# Delete row in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

how can i make it so this vba scripts deletes row containing a Percentage

```
Sub Macro2()

    Dim celltxt As String
    Dim a As Variant

    For Each i In Range(Cells(3, 2), Cells(160, 2))
        If i.Value > 1 Then
            i.Offset(0, 2).Value = i.Offset(0, 2).Value + 1
        End If

        If i.Value < 1 Then
            i.Offset(0, 2).Value = i.Offset(0, 2).Value + "NEI"
        End If

        If i.Value = "%" Then
            i.Offset(0, 2).Value = i.Offset(0, 3).Value + "joda"
        End If
    Next i

End Sub

Sub slettRadD()
    Range("D1:D160").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
End Sub

Sub SlettAlle()
    Range("A3:D160").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
End Sub
```

in this section

```
If i.Value = "%" Then
    i.Offset(0, 2).Value = i.Offset(0, 3).Value + "joda"
End If
```

i need it to delete the Horisontal row, or just delete the content in that cell. containing a percentage or percentage sign. just checked to see if i could even find it, but it does not seem work just adding a value in those colums.

Answer (score 2):

```
If i.Style = "Percent" Then
'Do Whatever here for example
  i.ClearContents
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

For formatted cells and if just cell contains (%)

```
If Right$(i.NumberFormat, 1) = "%"  Or i = "%" Then
```

Comment: What does that `$` in `Right$` do? Never seen that

Comment: It is a typed function. It is more efficient especially when doing string comparison in a loop. It is orders faster than just Right. It exists for many string functions e.g.  Mid$ . As it for strings you need to handle potential nulls. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/37899863/6241235

Comment: Interesting! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
If i.Value = "%" Or Right$(i.NumberFormat,1) = "%" Then i.EntireRow.Delete
```

I think it will do the job. But it is going to possibly skip some rows, because after deletion, it won't compensate de increment in the loop.

If you need to delete ranges, try doing it from the bottom-up or right-left

This link has options: [Reverse order of For Each loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24358183/reverse-order-of-for-each-loop)