# I want to get the "Current Folder" as listed in the Save As menu

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint, excel-2016

I am trying to get the value of the `Current Folder` as I see it when I click `Save As` and then see `Recent` locations.

For the exact application, I have a SharePoint library with my macro file set as the document template for "New" files.  I have a button that runs a save as command and want to save it to the current document set.

When I stop the macro and just go to Save As menu, then click "Recent" I see the correct document set as the "Current Folder" but I can not seem to get that location through VBA so I can automatically save the file there.  It seems like it's an application level property.

`ThisWorkbook.path`, `CurDir` and other commands either give me empty string or the path of the Excel application.

```
Thisworkbook.path
curDir
```

I only seem to get the application location itself such as:
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Root\Office16`
or empty string.

Comment: `Thisworkbook.path` is empty if the workbook the code is in was not saved yet.

Answer (score 2):

```vb
Dim path As String
path = Application.RecentFiles(1).Path
path = Left$(path, InStrRev(path, Application.PathSeparator))
```

Comment: Note that it will return a path including the file name if you want a path you must strip of the file name `path = Left$(path, InStrRev(path, Application.PathSeparator))`

Comment: @Pᴇʜ, thank you. I was just about to update the answer will do so now.  Thanks a lot. Why that $, please? EDIT:  thank you once again. I will update that then

Comment: `Left$()` returns a `String` while `Left()` returns a `Variant` so the `Left$()` should be faster. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37899862/difference-between-left-and-left-function-in-access